# Getting multiple vars from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to move 2 variables from my database to javascript, but the things I tried so far didn't work out.

Up to now I've tried ajax but as far as I know I can't send them separately which is necessary.
 
Putting the variable in the url isn't an option either since it requires refreshing the page. Because the vars are used to make changes in the css and the script needs to run multiple times each run will undo the changes.
I've also tried to use `<?php $var ?>` within java script. Though this works for vars outside of the function, it does not work for any var within the function.

This is the script I'm using at the moment to test the script, any suggestions are welcome.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["colourcheck"])){
    $colour = "red";
    $number = 1;
    echo $colour, $number;
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        function checkcolour() {
            var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "test2.php");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                    var colour = ajax.responseText;
                    _("unamestatus").innerHTML = colour;
                }
            }
            ajax.send("colourcheck=");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="colour 1" onclick="checkcolour()">1</div>
    <div class="colour 2" onclick="checkcolour()">2</div>
    <div class="colour 3" onclick="checkcolour()">3</div>
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can receive multiple data bits from PHP (JSON is a good way to do this) and then parse out the individual values you require.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use server values in Javascript use data-attributes in your tags. Ex:

```
<input id="my_input" name="color" data-identifier='<?=$server_value?>' />
```

Now in JS you can get it anywhere like:
    // Jquery
    $(function() {
      alert($('#my_input').data('identifier'));
    })

```
//Plain JS
document.getElementById('my_input').dataset.identifier;
```

Hope this help you.